# Object size difference in 32 bit and 64 bit systems in Java

Tags: java, object, memory, memory-management, jvm

I came across an interview question:

```
class Test {
    int a ; 
    int b;
    char c;
}
```

How much memory object of this class will take and why when implemented on:

a) 32-bit computer

b) 64-bit computer

I got the answer as:

```
For 32-bit: 4+4+2+8 = 18 bytes
For 64-bit: 4+4+2+16 = 26 bytes
```

Due to some extra memory allocated which is 8 bytes in 32-bit system and 16 bytes in 64-bit system, in addition to the normal size of object.

Can you please give some explanation for this statement.

P.S.: I also want to share an answer I got from another source (can't rely upon, wanted to verify):

In 32 bit pc object occupies 8 bytes more than the actual obj size as defined by its data members ..... and in 64 bit pc object occupies 16 bytes more than actual object size as defined by its data members .... now the ques arises why it happens ... the reason behind it as far as i know is ::: in 32 bit pc first 8 bytes are reserved by JVM for referring to class definitions, alignment ,spaces for super class and sub classes etc .. and for 64 bit it reserves 16 bytes for these .. There is a formula for calculating how much heap space is required by an object when it is created and it is calculated as ..... . . Shallow Heap Size = [reference to the class definition] + space for super class fields + space for instance fields + [alignment]

How do you calculate how much memory does the object “itself” require? Apparently there is a formula for it:

Shallow Heap Size = [reference to the class definition] + space for super class fields + space for instance fields + [alignment]

Does not seem too helpful, eh? Let’s try to apply the formula using the following sample code:

```
class X {
  int a;
  byte b;
  java.lang.Integer c = new java.lang.Integer();
}
class Y extends X {
  java.util.List d;
  java.util.Date e;
}
```

Now, the question we strive to answer is – how much shallow heap size does an instance of a Y require? Lets start calculating it, assuming that we are on a 32-bit x86 architecture:

As a starting point – Y is a subclass of X, so its size includes “something” from the super class. Thus, before calculating the size of Y, we look into calculating the shallow size of X.

Jumping into the calculations on X, first 8 bytes are used to refer its class definition. This reference is always present in all Java objects and is used by JVM to define the memory layout of the following state. It also has three instance variables – an int, an Integer and a byte. Those instance variables require heap as follows:

a byte is what it is supposed to be. 1 byte in a memory.
an int in our 32 bit architecture requires 4 bytes.
a reference to the Integer requires also 4 bytes. Note that when calculating retained heap, we should also take into account the size of a primitive wrapped into the Integer object, but as we are calculating shallow heap here, we only use the reference size of 4 bytes in our calculations.
So – is that it? Shallow heap of X = 8 bytes from reference to the class definition + 1 byte (the byte) + 4 bytes (the int) + 4 bytes (reference to the Integer) = 17 bytes? In fact – no. What now comes into play is called alignment (also called padding). It means that the JVM allocates the memory in multiples of 8 bytes, so instead of 17 bytes we would allocate 24 bytes if we would create an instance of X.

If you could follow us until here, good, but now we try to get things even more complex. We are NOT creating an instance of X, but an instance of Y. What this means is – we can deduct the 8 bytes from the reference to the class definition and the alignment. It might not be too obvious at first place but – did you note that while calculating the shallow size of X we did not take into account that it also extends java.lang.Object as all classes do even if you do not explicitly state it in your source code? We do not have to take into account the header sizes of superclasses, because JVM is smart enough to check it from the class definitions itself, instead of having to copy it into the object headers all the time.

The same goes for alignment – when creating an object you only align once, not at the boundaries of superclass/subclass definitions. So we are safe to say that when creating a subclass to X you will only inherit 9 bytes from the instance variables.

Finally we can jump to the initial task and start calculating the size of Y. As we saw, we have already lost 9 bytes to the superclass fields. Let’s see what will be added when we actually construct an instance of Y.

Y’s headers referring to its class definition consume 8 bytes. The same as with previous ones.
The Date is a reference to an object. 4 bytes. Easy.
The List is a reference to a collection. Again 4 bytes. Trivial.
So in addition to the 9 bytes from the superclass we have 8 bytes from the header, 2×4 bytes from the two references (the List and the Date). The total shallow size for the instance of Y would be 25 bytes, which get aligned to 32.

Comment: I would imagine the answer would correctly be "undefined".  Putting aside the uselessness of this as an interview question, did the interviewers specify a certain JVM implementation?

Comment: @MarkPeters I read this question on net, that is why I thought to confirm this, here.

Comment: Obviously this is a ridiculous question since (among other reasons) there are different "64-bit computers" with different processors.  My understanding is that a 64-bit 80x86/Pentium-based processor still has all the 32-bit (and 16-bit instructions) that their 32-bit cousins have, so there's no inherent reason to take up 64 bits to store a 32-bit integer.  Unless it somehow simplifies the implementation in other ways.

Comment: Edited. Added an answer from some other source, but do want to get it clear.

Comment: If you are asked this in an interview, don't say "it's undefined". Anyone can say that - it says nothing positive about you. Attempt to answer and explain what you know about headers, word-sizes, architectures, memory alignment, etc. Qualify the answer if you must at the end.

Answer (score 11):

Depends on JVM. As to HotSpot JVM, the correct answer is:

- **32-bit JVM: 24 bytes** = align8(4 bytes mark_word + 4 bytes class reference + 4 + 4 + 2 bytes field data)
- **64-bit JVM -XX:+UseCompressedOops: 24 bytes** = align8(8 bytes mark_word + 4 bytes class reference + 4 + 4 + 2 bytes field data)
- **64-bit JVM -XX:-UseCompressedOops: 32 bytes** = align8(8 bytes mark_word + 8 bytes class reference + 4 + 4 + 2 bytes field data)

Comment: Are you sure align8 can be applied once across the the entire object? According to [this article](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/dangerous-code-how-to-be-unsafe-with-java-classes-objects-in-memory/6/), each superclass is separately aligned to WORD size. In the case of a 64-bit JVM with UseCompressedOops, that would give us `align8(align8(8 mark_word + 4 class ref) + align8(4 + 4 + 2 field data))` = 28 bytes, rather than 24. Unless header bytes don't follow the superclass alignment policy.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, 4 bytes in the headers following class ref are used for object fields, too (unless a field is `long` or `double` which should be 8-byte aligned).

Answer (score 4):

I would answer such an interview Question as follows:

- It is not specified ...
- It potentially depends on the Java implementation (i.e. the Java release, vendor, and target instruction set / architecture) as well as 32 versus 64 bit.
- The object consists of the fields (whose alignment is platform specific) with an object header (whose size is platform specific) and the size is then rounded up to a platform-specific heap object size granularity.
- A better approach is to measure the object size (e.g. using TLAB on a modern HotSpot JVM).
- While the object sizes may vary, the meaning of `int` and `char` does not.  An `int` is always 32 bit signed, and a `char` is always 16 bit unsigned.

---

If the interviewer told you this:

> For 32-bit: 4+4+2+8 = 18 bytes

That probably means an `int` and `int` and a `char` plus 2 32-bit words of object header.  However, I think that he is wrong.  In fact the `2` should probably be a `4` because I believe that fields are *typically* stored as 4 (or 8) bytes aligned on a 32-bit word boundary

> For 64-bit: 4+4+2+16 = 26 bytes

As above, but with 2 64-bit words of object header.  Again, I don't think this is correct.

> Due to some extra memory allocated which is 8 bytes in 32-bit system and 16 bytes in 64-bit system, in addition to the normal size of object.

The granularity of heap allocation is some multiple 2 words.

But I would stress that this is not necessarily correct.  Certainly, nothing in the official JVM specs require objects to be represented like that.

Comment: +1 Agree you can only talk about a specific version of a JVM.  HotSpot/OpenJDK is a good place to start ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky question.

If you consider variable size then it doesn't change. Both 32 and 64 bits will give you 24 bytes. However, the 64 bit will load more on the memory and that will consume more memory.

It helps to remember that 32 and 64 are what the CPU can handle, not the amount of memory that can be allocated.

For a reference, see this statement from Red Hat:

**9.1. 32-bit vs. 64-bit JVM**

> A question commonly raised when discussing performance is which gives better overall performance: 32-bit or 64-bit JVM? It would seem that a 64-bit JVM hosted by a 64-bit operating system should perform better than a 32-bit JVM on modern, 64-bit capable hardware. To try and provide some quantitative data on the topic, testing was performed with an industry standard workload. All tests were run on the same system, with the same operating system, JVM version and settings with one exception described below.

[image]

Source: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/chap-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Java_Virtual_Machine_Tuning.html

Comment: Say, some interviewer ask this question from me in future, then what should be my answer? Because, frankly speaking, I didn't got this concept hitherto.

Comment: just say "same amount of memory for the heap".

Comment: If you turn off the TLAB `-XX:-UseTLAB` you will get much more accurate accounting.

Answer (score 2):

To get accurate accounting you can turn off the TLAB.  There is still the risk of a GC changignt eh result, but it is much less hit and miss.

```
public class Main {
    static class Test {
        int a ;
        int b;
        char c;
    }

    public static void main(String sdf[]) throws Exception {
        // warmup
        new Test();
        long start = memoryUsed();
        Object o = new Test();
        long used = memoryUsed() - start;
        System.out.printf("Memory used for %s, was %,d bytes%n", o.getClass(), used);

    }

    public static long memoryUsed() {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    }
}
```

Note: for large tests, it can help if you increase the Eden size to 1 GB or more.

```
Memory used for class Main$Test, was 24 bytes
```

> For 64-bit: 4+4+2+16 = 26 bytes

This is not possible as the HotSpot JVM only ever allocates multiples of 8 bytes.  BTW You can increase the minimum allocation unit in Java 8 to 16 or 32 bytes.

The header is 12 bytes so the size is

4 + 4 + 2 + 12 (header) + 2 (padding to 8 byte multiple) = 24

Run with `-XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16` you see

```
Memory used for class Main$Test, was 32 bytes
```

This raises the question, why would you do this if it wastes memory?

The benefit relates to compressed oops which allows you to use 32-bit references in a 64-bit JVM.  Normally compressed oops can address 32 GB because it knows all objects are aligned by 8 bytes i.e. you can address 4 G * 8 bytes.  However if you increase the byte alignment to 16, you can address 4G * 16 bytes or 64 GB using compressed oops.  I believe you can use a 32 byte alignment, but this wastes more memory than it saves in most cases.

Comment: Can you confirm that the 12 byte header is not separately aligned from the fields, as I suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836854/object-size-difference-in-32-bit-and-64-bit-systems-in-java#comment59197167_24841871